# Does Wii U support any form of voice chat?

Tags: wii-u, voice-chat

I personally thought that there is no, but I found [Ear Force NLa](http://www.turtlebeach.com/product-detail/nintendo-headsets/ear-force-nla/36) which is a Wii U branded headset. So presumably there should be support for chat. Is it supported in limited games only, or there is special application for this (I can't find any)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is handled on a per-game basis.

For an example, off the top of my head, **Monster Hunter 3 Ultimate** supports Voice Chat -- and the Gamepad itself includes a Mic, so you don't *need* to spend the extra cash, though the quality is nothing like a dedicated headset.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I assume build mic is very bad for intense chat :)

Comment: Btw, is there any way I could know if game supports chat?